# If $P(A) = \frac13, P(B) = \frac14$, can if be true that $A$ is a subset of $B$?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I think not right because the size of set $A$ would be bigger than set $B$? not sure...thanks!

Comment: Is there a difference between $b$ and $B$?  If not, sds's solution is correct.

Answer (score 3):

No, because probability is a [measure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Measure_(mathematics)) and thus monotonic: $A\subseteq B \implies P(A)\leq P(B)$.

Answer (score 0):

As a counterexample think of event $A$ as tossing a dice and even number shows up and $B$ to be the event as tossing a dice and odd number shows up , then $P(A) = \frac{1}{2}$ and $P(B) = \frac{1}{2}$ , so is  $A \subseteq B$, No! as $A = \{ 2,4,6\}$ and $B = \{ 1,3,5\}$.

for considering the case of $P(A) < P(B)$,simply consider a $7$ sided dice.
where $P(A) = \frac{3}{7}$ and $P(B) = \frac{4}{7}$ so here too you see that is $A \subseteq B$ ?, No!.

Also there is a reverse result on this as stated by sds,that is if $A \subseteq B$ then $P(A) \leq P(B)$,but converse doesnot hold in general.